# Getting text from React wrapped span using webdriverio

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mocha.js, webdriver-io

I'm writing tests for a React front end application.
One of the tests must check how a value was returned from the server.
Namely, I have the following spans:

```
<span id='result'>
    <!-- our version of react wraps the resulting text by default -->
    <span data-reactid>the actual result</span>
</span>


// test.js   
getResult() {
    let a = browser.getText('#result span');
    console.log('a:', a);
}  // unfortunately, getting it this way will mean having to rewrite the test once we upgrade to a newer version of React (after 15 is does not do the wrapping anymore)
```

So, basically.. How can I get the text value in such a way that either the span generated by react has an id or class... or any other way in which changes to the dom structure would not mean having to rewrite tests?

Comment: have you tried just `browser.getText('#result')`?

Comment: yes.. but because react always wraps a <span> around things,  I have to use browser.getText('#result span');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how to do it with just the webDriver API, but you could use some javascript to get the value. Something like this:

```
var id = 'result';

client.execute(function(a) {
    return document.getElementById(a).textContent;
}, id).then(function(ret) {
     console.log(ret.value); // outputs: the actual result
});
```

By using textContent, even though your selector targets the parent span, it will ignore the child `<span>` tags when outputting the text.

Comment: excellent! Using the webdriver, I will just get the parent, and execute this on it. Thanks.